# Sharepoint Wiki

Tags: sharepoint, wiki

We use TFS in our environment.  Is there a way I can set up a Wiki under M$ Sharepoint?

Comment: What version of Sharepoint do you use?

Comment: if you put a -1, please explain why.

Comment: +1 to the question, but I suspect your -1 came from the rather childish use of "M$"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On TFS 2008 from the web interface:

1) click "Site Actions"

2) select "Create"

3) fill in the fields, select "Collaboration | Wiki Site" as the template

4) click "Create"

Should be the same steps for TFS 2005 and workgroup editions of both.